# Can you tell me where i did wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, error-handling, syntax-error

Uncaught TypeError: planet.innerText is not a function

```
        .addEventListener("click",function() {
        let planet= document.getElementById("redplanet")  
        planet.innerText("Nothing to report");
        planet.classList.remove("alert");
        })
document.getElementById("greenplanet").classList.add("alert")
```

html code: ```

```
 So my js code isn't working in inspect it says that line 23 is not a function any solution to solve this?
```

Comment: hi please provide us completed with screenshot or code snippet to see what the actual problem with your code thanks

Comment: https://imgur.com/7CD2Uwi

Comment: https://imgur.com/h4KVHbX

Comment: https://imgur.com/K9lhvn9

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite clear. `DOMElement.innerText` is not a function. You are supposed to use it as a property:

```
const planet = document.getElementById('redplanet');
planet.innerText = 'Hello world';
```

A live example can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ga1ytz0j/

For more information, please visit:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: so i put it out of the function() but how i make the button reset work right then?

Comment: @PiturcaStefan Could you elaborate on the functionality of your reset button because it doesn't appear to be in the scope of the question you asked or the code you provided?

Comment: <input type="button" value="check" id="check">
   <input type="button" value="reset" id="reset"> that's the html code so one modifies the text the other resets it back to the way it was how i make the button work and don't have any errors?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the reset button to set the planet text to `Nothing to report` and the `alert` class to be removed from the `redplanet` element @PiturcaStefan ? If so, have a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ga1ytz0j/1/

Comment: You're welcome @PiturcaStefan , Don't forget to mark your answer and close the question

Comment: how i do that?,sorry kinda new to this

Comment: @PiturcaStefan https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

It is not a function.  It is a property.

Use

```
planet.innerText = "Nothing to report";
```